# Can't set default value for column

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I can't set default value for for column in my table. I see lot of many example, but i can't resolve my issue. I have table with two columns: id, name. I'm need, if id == null, then set default value.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('val_seq')
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) VALUES (null, 'test_name')
```

I receive error: `null value in column "id" violates not-null constant. How fixed this?`

Comment: Your database system can't be MySQL and PostgreSQL at the same time unless you are looking your a solution that works in both..As `nextval()` is not valid MySQL syntax i assume MySQL is a mis tag and can be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try not to include the column that you want to use the default value for in your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('test_name')
```

The default constraint will provide a default value for a column IF no other value is specified.